Regular expression for changing // comment to /* */
If I run the following powershell with embedded C#, it works
$Source = @"
public class BasicTest
{
    // Multiply two numbers
    public int Multiply(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a * b);
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source
$BasicTestObject = New-Object BasicTest
$BasicTestObject.Multiply(5, 2)

If I put the C# bit in a file BasicTest.cs and use get-content, it fails
public class BasicTest
{
    // Multiply two numbers
    public int Multiply(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a * b);
    }
}

The powershell code
$Source = Get-Content -Path ".\BasicTest.cs"
Add-Type -TypeDefinition "$Source"
$BasicTestObject = New-Object BasicTest
$BasicTestObject.Multiply(5, 2)

There is a big error message that starts with
Add-Type : c:\Users\xwb\AppData\Local\Temp\1bpg0e0c.0.cs(1) : } expected

This is because the entire file is read as 1 line and the // comments out the rest of the file.  If I change the // comment to /* */
public class BasicTest
{
    /* Multiply two numbers */
    public int Multiply(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a * b);
    }
}

the code works and I get the result 10.
The question is, in Visual Studio or VS Code or Notepad++, how do I replace all // comments with /* */.  I can find the comment with
//.*

What do I put in the replacement bit?  I've unsuccessfully tried
/*.**/
/*{.*}*/


Are you solving the right problem? $MultiLine = [System.String]::Join([System.Environment]::NewLine, $Source) would give you the source   with newlines still in place when you control converting the array Get-Content returns into a single string, and then you can use $MultiLine thereafter and don't need source files to be manually changed.

Found another way Get-Content -Path <filename> -Raw.  Seems to get round the single line problem.

EDIT: regex updated. Thanks @Toto
The match regex for this is ^(.*?)//(.*), the replace regex is $1/*$2*/.
This will remove the first iteration of two consecutive / and incapsulate the line between /* and */, starting from the position of the aforementioned first //
example:
https://regex101.com/r/wJCdPt/1

FYI: [^/{2}] matches any character that is not / or { or 2 or }. If you have the line: a = 2; // comment, it will not be modified

@Toto Fixed, I hope.

Not really. Use ^(.*?)//(.*) demo

@Toto done, thanks
